# React.js Authentication Problem Even I Get the Token

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a site with basic auth with Spring. I use Redux. I'm sending a request to "/auth" in the backend. After successfully logging in, i get those:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycuuw.png)

As you can see I have successfully logged in.

But i still can not be authenticated. I did not refresh the page i did nothing but this is the console output. By the way, postman is working fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7PpG.png)

This is part of apiCalls:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const signup = (body) => {
      return  axios.post('/users', body);
};

export const login = creds => {
      return axios.post('/auth', {}, {auth:creds});
};
export const getMarketItemsSortByDate = () => {
      return axios.get("/market/last");
}
```

This is configureStore:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware,compose} from 'redux';
import authReducer from './authReducer';
import SecureLS from 'secure-ls';
import thunk  from 'redux-thunk';
const secureLS = new SecureLS();


const getStateFromStorage = () => {
      const hoaxAuth = secureLS.get('hoax-auth');
        let stateInLocalStorage = {
            isLoggedIn:false,
            username:undefined,
            mail:undefined,
            balance:undefined,
            password:undefined
        };

        if(hoaxAuth){
             stateInLocalStorage =  hoaxAuth;
        }

        return stateInLocalStorage;
}

const updateStateInStorage = newState => {
      secureLS.set('hoax-auth', newState);
}

  const configureStore = () => {
        const initialState = getStateFromStorage();
        const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
        const store = createStore(authReducer, initialState, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
        store.subscribe(()=> {
              updateStateInStorage(store.getState());
        })
        return store;
  }

  export default configureStore;
```

This is authActions :

```
import * as ACTIONS from "./Constants";
import {login} from '../api/apiCalls';

export const logoutSuccess = () => {
      return {
            type: ACTIONS.LOGOUT_SUCCESS
      };
}

export const loginSuccess = authState => {
      return {
        type: ACTIONS.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: authState
      };
    };

    export const loginHandler = credentials => {
      return async function(dispatch) {
        const response = await login(credentials);
        const authState = {
          ...response.data,
          password: credentials.password,
        };
        console.log(authState);
        dispatch(loginSuccess(authState));
        return response;
      };
    };
```

And this is authReducer:

```
import * as ACTIONS from './Constants';

const defaultState = {
      isLoggedIn:false,
        username:undefined,
        mail:undefined,
        balance:undefined,
        password:undefined
    }
    
    const authReducer = (state= { ...defaultState},action) => {
      if(action.type === ACTIONS.LOGOUT_SUCCESS){
      return defaultState;
      } else if(action.type === ACTIONS.LOGIN_SUCCESS){
      return {
            ...action.payload,
            isLoggedIn:true
      }
      }
      return state;
    }

    export default authReducer;
```

Everything is fine with postman so problem should be inside React.js

Comment: Are you passing, into the header, your authorization token? If so - where in the code? Your api calls code only contains for singup and login. Nothing for sending other APIs to backend for, like in the picture, `market/last/` that requires the token to authorize you.

Comment: I didnt add those parts

Comment: Problem is your `const getMarketItemsSortByDate` method in `apiCalls`. It would seem that the data from  URL `<domain>/market/last` is only available for the logged in user. In your case - even tho the user logged in and received the authorization token, you are actually not sending the authorization token back to the server when requesting for `market/last` URL. This way server thinks you are not logged in and sends you back a 401 error.

Comment: It should go something like this `return axios.get("/market/last", {headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json','Acess-Control-Allow-Origin':'*','Accept': "application/json",'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token}});` NOTE the token is the token you recieve back from the server (first photo > header > autorization: <token>). This way server can indentify who you are. In your case you might need to change token type (from bearer) to whatever you are using and also add/remove headers. Its just an example

Comment: There are some items on homepage. I just want only logged-in users can see them. After successful login, it redirects to homepage but it says unauthorized. Do i have to add all of those parameters each request?

Comment: It's important to follow atleast the basic programming patterns such as DRY. you should just have 2 methods for get and getAuthentificated. As a parameter you just pass the URL that you should execute a get method. So all methods, requiring authorization, will execute thru `getAuth(' /market/last')` and etc reducing the code, making it easily maintainable and only requiring the need of auth in header once.

Comment: About the home page - see if the user is logged in on ur frontend. If he then load components requiring authorization. In those components u execute your `getAuth` method, or however you wanna call it. You add an error checking that if there is an error then just return an empty fragment. Better - redo a check to backend with the token to check if its still valid. If its not - logout the user and redirect back to login page. There are many ways - all having pros and cons. It just depends how complex you wanna do. I have few ideas

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set [`withCredentials`](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) for each requests you made with axios that requires the token as such:

```
export const login = creds => {
      return axios.post('/auth', {}, {auth:creds, withCredentials:true});
};
export const getMarketItemsSortByDate = () => {
      return axios.get("/market/last", {}, {withCredentials:true});
}
```

which allows the access token to be set and to be sent along with the request.

Comment: I set withCredentials , but unfortunately did not work.

Comment: What happens if you add `auth:creds` for the GET request?